# Must Check box to submit form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Trying to create a form that will force people to select the checkbox with the phrase "I accept the terms and conditions" in order to send the form.

This is what I have but it is not submitting the form — I get an error.

Javascript that I have placed in the header:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!--

   function validate_form ( )
   {
   valid = true;

   if ( document.form1.cb.checked == false )
   {
   alert ( "Please check the Terms & Conditions box ." );
   valid = false;
   }

   return valid;
   }

   //-->
   </script>
```

Form:

```html
    <form action="/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl" method="POST" name="frmOne"  id="frmOne">
    <input type=hidden name="recipient" value="XXX@XXX.com"/>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" style="margin-top:-20px">
    <tr>
    <td width="50%" valign="top">
    <br/>
      <p><span id="sprytextfield1">
    <label for="Full Name">Full Name (First and Last): </label>
    <input name="Full Name" type="text" id="name" tabindex="10" size="60" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"><br />Please provide information.</span></span> </p>
    <p><span id="sprytextfield2">
    <label for="Your Email">Your e-mail address: </label>
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="60" />
    <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg"></span></span>  </p>
    <p><span id="sprytextfield3">
    <label for="Phone Number"> Phone Number: </label>
    <input name="Phone Number" type="text" id="phone" size="60" />
    <span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg"><br />Invalid format.</span><span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"><br/>A phone number is required.</span></span></p>
    <p class="text">
      <span id="sprytextfield4">
    <label for="Nature Of The Accident">Nature of Accident, i.e. slip and fall, motor vehicle accident, etc.:  </label>
    <input name="Nature Of The Accident" type="text" id="natureOfAccident" size="60" />
    </span></p>
    <p><span id="sprytextfield5">
    <label for="Date Of The Accident">Date of the Accident: </label>
    <input name="Date Of The Accident" type="text" id="dateOfAccident" size="60" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"><br />Please provide information.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg"><br />Invalid format.</span></span></p>
    <p class="text">
    </td>

    <td width="50%" valign="top">

    <p class="text">
    <span id="sprytextarea1"> 
    <label for="Description Of The Injury"><br />Brief Description of your Injuries: </label>
    <textarea name="Description Of The Injury" cols="45" rows="4" id="descriptionOfInjury">
    </textarea> 
    <span class="textareaRequiredMsg"><br />Please provide information.</span></span></p>
    <p class="text">
    <span id="sprytextarea2">
    <label for="Description Of The Accident">Brief Description of the Accident:</label>
    <textarea name="Description Of The Accident" id="descriptionOfAccident" cols="45" rows="4"></textarea>
    <span class="textareaRequiredMsg"><br />
    Please provide information.</span></span></p>
    <p class="text">
    <span id="sprytextfield6">
    <label for="How Did You Hear About Us">How did you hear about us?: </label>
    <input name="How Did You Hear About Us" type="text" id="howDidYouHear" size="56" />
    <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"><br />Please provide information.</span></span>  </p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="agree_terms" id="disclaimer" />
    <label for="disclaimer">I have read the Disclaimer</label>
    <br/><br />
    &nbsp;<input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset Form" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="Form Action" id="send" tabindex="100" value="Submit" />

    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var sprytextfield1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield1", "none", {validateOn:["blur", "change"]});
var sprytextfield2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield2", "email", {validateOn:["blur", "change"], isRequired:false});
var sprytextfield3 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield3", "phone_number", {validateOn:["blur"], useCharacterMasking:true});
var sprytextfield4 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield4", "none", {isRequired:false, validateOn:["blur", "change"]});
var sprytextfield5 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield5", "date", {hint:"dd/mm/yyyy", validateOn:["blur", "change"], format:"dd/mm/yyyy"});
var sprytextarea1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextarea("sprytextarea1", {validateOn:["blur", "change"]});
var sprytextarea2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextarea("sprytextarea2", {validateOn:["blur", "change"]});
var sprytextfield6 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationTextField("sprytextfield6", "none", {validateOn:["blur", "change"], hint:"Google, etc"});
//-->
</script></div>
```

Comment: I can see neither `form1` nor `cb` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the form and elements wrong, try something like this:

```
<form name="frmOne" method="POST" onSubmit="return checkForm(frmOne);" action="/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl">

<script>
function checkForm(form) 
{
    if(!form.agree.checked) 
    { 
        alert("You must agree to this disclaimer before applying.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

I hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

Change `<form action="/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl" method="POST" name="frmOne"  id="frmOne">` to `<form action="/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl" method="POST" name="frmOne"  id="frmOne" onSubmit="validate_form();">`

What other errors are you getting?

and change `document.form1.cb.checked` to `document.frmOne.agree.checked`

Comment: The changes work to a degree the form now will tell me that there is an error and I need to select that I have read the disclaimer.  However after I click ok it will still proceed to the submit.

Comment: Change `<form action="/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl" method="POST" name="frmOne" id="frmOne" onSubmit="validate_form();">` to `<form action="/cgi-bin/FormMail.pl" method="POST" name="frmOne" id="frmOne" onSubmit="return validate_form();">`

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with `document.getElementById("disclaimer").checked == false`.